# knockout.js with jQuery 1.9.0 breaks in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js

This code is taken directly from knockoutjs.com tutorials:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: months">
    <li>
        The current item is: <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        months: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'etc' ]
    });
</script>
```

When I run this on http://jsfiddle.net/SaZv8/ with IE 8 it works as long as you don't include jQuery 1.9.0. When including 1.9.0 you get a `Object doesn't support this property or method` error.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: You should update to [knockoutjs 2.2.1](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js) for jQuery 1.9.0, however this error is a jsFiddle problem with IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error happens in jsfiddle's code: 'heyoffline.js' has an addEventListener call which is not supported in IE8.
Note: I can reproduce it with other libraries selected, so it's not related to the jQuery1.9.

Comment: The heyoffline-error also happens, but it's not the only error. I get the same problem on my local machine too. And when switching to jQuery 1.8.3 it works.

Comment: You are right, my comment didn't answer your question. But mhu is also right: seems knockout 2.2.1 is required for jquery 1.9. Here is code: http://jsfiddle.net/jBTmX
First of all it confuses IE8 and hides the js code in jsfiddle (type an enter in the JS window to make it appear). But it works. However if you change the version to 2.2.0 then it produces the error you experience.

Comment: yes, I think mhu is right. Seems like knockout 2.2.1 is required for jQuert 1.9